# How to install mods for Skyrim on Playonlinux?

Tags: wine, steam

I was successful last night running Playonlinux and installing steam and accessing my game account with my already purchased skyrim game. I am almost finished installing Skyrim. I am do not know how to incorporate mods to the game from playonlinux and I am worried that that will be a very difficult task to complete. How does one install mods for skyrim on playonlinux?

Comment: I made changes to the question. Let me know if this question is better posed. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option would be to image your windows drive and run it as a guest os under virtual box. You won't have to buy a new copy and you'll have all your favourite mods from windows because you copied the entire drive and since you'll be running it under windows and not wine you'll have no wine debugging. I'm not sure what the game performance will be like. Maybe someone else can chime in with a better answer but if I were in your shoes I'd start testing there. Of course reviewing the respective license agreements to insure that this complies is legally necessary. There's a good although lengthy writeup on how to do this here. https://forums.virtualbox.org/viewtopic.php?f=2&t=31759#p172460

**Backup, backup, backup. One mistake can lose a lifetime of data.**

Comment: I like your answer. My computer contains two harddrives, one for windows and one for linux. I dual boot everytime I start the computer. Is it possible to run the game from the other harddrive on the linux os? Does this relate to your answer? Please tell me what I can do with my dual system. I have the option to just run skyrim on windows, but I love linux too much.

Comment: If you like my answer, Please upvote it. I'll dig a bit deeper into virtualbox tomorrow for the details but I'm sure there is a way you can point the VM to the windows drive. The game performance is likely to suffer though as virtualbox just emulates the hardware.

Comment: I upvoted your comment last night. Did it work?

Comment: @linuxfreebird No, you upvoted the comment. The community has put your question on hold as "opinion based" You are allowed to edit the question.....

Comment: I upvoted the answer. Doe anyone have any suggestions on how to narrow the scope of this question?

Comment: @linuxfreebird As stated above... If this question can be reworded to fit the rules in the help center, please edit the question or leave a comment. It's your question, But if the answer fits perhaps something along the lines of can I use my existing Windows installation under Ubuntu.. I don't know if that would satisfy dobey, Braiam, Avinash Raj, Hadi, and souravc but all things are possible.. :-D